# Cypress: not able to retrieve the API respose data

Tags: cypress

I have to test 'id' and "prevTrId" for below API response

```
{"result":{"code":200,"status":"OK"},"securities":[{"id":"3133H","sec":"USIG//FFCB","xcc":0,"liq":"9","dr":"-434.114562","dur":"5.411709","obs":[{"d":1549918953000,"bps":"0.001751","m":231,"prevTrId":"2019021AM_530","apc":{"tt":"-0.000328","tc":"0.001751","tta":"-0.033","tca":"0.175892"}}]}]}
```

Cypress code:

```
describe('API Testing with Cypress', () => {
    var responsebodydata

    it('Validate the header', () => {
     cy.request('http://pTe-GPbt-ws.ga.data.com:9082/v1/testing/raw?dateFrom=01-01-2019&dateTo=07-17-2019&reqId=xxxxxx-secIds=3133EJ5H&tradeSizeFrom=10000&tradeSizeTo=5000&tradeSide=BUY&cepSide=BID&cepCompareToTrades=&cepCompareToQuotes').then((response)=> {


   responsebodydata = response.body
   cy.log(responsebodydata)

 expect(response.body).to.have.property('id', '3133H')     

      })
  })
})
```

`cy.log(responsebodydata)` is printing the result as

```
{result: {code: 200, status: OK}, securities: [Object{7}]}
```

and I'm getting an assertion error

> Expected { Object (result, securities) } to have a property 'id'

Can anyone provide some ideas how to get the 'id' from the response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to compare the `id` property:

```
expect(response.body.securities[0]).to.have.property('id', '3133H')
```

This to compare the `d` property:

```
expect(response.body.securities[0].obs[0]).to.have.property('d', 1549918953000);
```

This to compare the `prevTrId` property:

```
expect(response.body.securities[0].obs[0]).to.have.property('prevTrId', '2019021AM_530');
```

Comment: Thanks For the reply Yevhen:  The assertion is failing.    I just try to print the value responsebodydata = response.body.securities[0]
cy.log(responsebodydata)  and   it is returning "Object{7}" not 'id'

Comment: It should work if all your data in question are correct. Do you want to print all keys of the object or assert id? If you want just to print all keys of the object, call the `JSON.stringify(responsebodydata)` function.

Comment: Yes, it is working fine, Thanks.

but for the same following response data, I could not able to access "d":1549918953000, is there any different why i could able to access it :

"securities":[{"id":"3133H","sec":"USIG//FFCB","xcc":0,"liq":"9","dr":"-434.114562","dur":"5.411709","obs":[{"d":1549918953000,"bps":"0.001751","m":231,"prevTrId":"2019021AM_530","apc":{"tt":"-0.000328","tc":"0.001751","tta":"-0.033","tca":"0.175892"}}]}]}

Comment: Hi Yeven, Could you please look at below query : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57133812

Comment: Hi @SmrutiranjanaRay. Only you can mark this answer as solved/resolved, upvote it and mark it as accepted answer while I will look at your new question.

Comment: Hi Yevhen, I have accepted the answer and upvote it.

Comment: Great, thank you! It will be great if you will mark this answer as useful too. I have answered on your new question. Have a great day!

Comment: I have tried to mark it useful but as i have less than 15 reputation, it only take is as recorded

Comment: Hey @SmrutiranjanaRay! Now you can (:

Comment: Yes @Yevhen Done :)