# Cypress: Could not able to retrieve a specific data from downloaded excel-sheet

Tags: cypress

Below is the Excel from which i need 'SIP' data '37046654'

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfX4s.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZNVp.png)

I have tried below cypress code but it is failing as it is expecting all the data in the excel-sheet

**Cypress Code:**

```js
describe('API Testing with Cypress', () => {
 
    it('Validate the header', () => {
  
responsebodydata = cy.readFile('C:/Users/backNew.csv').should('eq','37046654')
  
  cy.log (responsebodydata)
   
     })
  })
```

Assertion result: Failed with timeout by following output:

expected 'SIP\tAsset Class\tSector\tObservations\tCDP Proximity\r\n37046789\tUP1G\tRetail\t1\t100\r\n37046654\tUG8G\tRetail\t1\t0' to equal '37046ADD'

Can anyone give some idea how can i get / check '37046654' exist in the excel-sheet or not

Comment: You should post your table as text.

Comment: Could you please give some sample of code as example that help me to understand.

Comment: Table in Text format:
  SIP         ASSERT CLASS Sector Observation CDP Proximity
37046789 UP1G         Retails           1                             100
37046654 UG8G         Retail            1                                     1

(Table also added in image in the question)

Comment: Hey @SmrutiranjanaRay. Did it help you?

Comment: @Yevhen, Application is down, i will check and update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want just check that the `37046654` number is present in the `backNew.csv` file - use the `contains`.

```
responsebodydata = cy.readFile('C:/Users/backNew.csv').should('contains','37046654')
```

Comment: Cool. Glad that helped you!

Answer (score 0):

Complete Working Code -

```
<reference types="Cypress" />

describe('API Testing with Cypress', () => {

    var responsebodydata

    it('Validate the header', () => {

    responsebodydata = cy.readFile('C:/Users/sharma.al/backNew.csv').then((response)=> {

    responsebodydata = response.body
    cy.log(responsebodydata)
      
    responsebodydata = cy.readFile('C:/Users/sharma.al/backNew.csv').should('contains','37046654')
    
      })     
   })
})
```